# Node.js and Express - simplest cache approach

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, caching

Imagine an app with hundreds of users with small data (max 10 name/value pairs) but build on a system where to get to these data some complicated calculations have to be made.

The idea is that I have a system with 'history' and the history state is needed so its essential for the system to 'work through' the history to have last actual data.

Ok and this process takes time, but I thought, the only one who edits data in my case is the admin or admin events, so how about instead of computing the data for each and every user call I just:

- create a cache object (in memory?)
- compute the 'history' on admin events only (and server reboot)
- serve the users the data from this cache object without computation

Is this a good idea? And if so what is the best approach to achieve this?

I simply made a module called 'ServerData' that can hold all the user data in arrays and a custom function called 'serverDataUpdate()' that I call when needed.

Users get served whatever is needed from this cache module.

Im asking because this all seemed too easy, and I searched for cache approaches for Node and I saw some extra modules build for this purpose.

Can they offer anything better than this 'simple' approach?

It kinda feels almost too easy so Im not sure if I didnt miss something

Thank you

Comment: Maybe you should compute your data and cache them in the Redis server. It is simple to run and it is very fast. And maybe you can create a new nodejs process for handle computing the data and communicate with Seneca.js to update the data in the Redis server.

Comment: Thank you Milad for your reply I will have a look into it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think that it is an overkill to calculate just the same figures every time a request is received, yes, pre-calculate them and store them in memory - just to be served.

1. You will have to create routes to recalculate and update the cache when the calculation params are changed.
2. Keep in mind that you may have to resort to different approach in case you are going to host your application in a scalable container orchestration system like Kubernetes. In this case your application will be spawned and each of them will have its own cache.

Comment: Thank you Charlie for your comment - yes I thought that what I could be facing are issues with scalability but that is not the plan here. thank you again I just wanted to know if there is a big flaw in my concept or not.